# Insert into dictionary or fail if key already present without hashing twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to either insert a new key into a `dict` or fail if that key already exists without hashing twice?

From something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __hash__(self):
        print('MyClass.__hash__ called')
        return object.__hash__(self)

my_key = MyClass()
my_value = "my_string"
my_dict = {}
if my_key not in my_dict:
    my_dict[my_key] = my_value
else:
    raise ValueError
```

you can see that `__hash__` is called twice and this code doesn't  express the desired behavior of insertion or failure as an atomic operation.

Comment: Note that the problem you're trying to solve (avoiding calling `__hash__` twice) is probably not something you should bother with. Your hash function should be fast enough that you don't really care how often it gets called. If it's not, you're probably wasting your time using a dictionary instead of some other data structure with more costly lookups, since the dictionary's "fast" lookups won't actually be fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `setdefault` method of the dictionary:

```
if my_dict.setdefault(my_key, my_value) != my_value:
     raise ValueError
```

`setdefault` assigns the second argument to the key given by the first argument, but only if the key doesn't already exist in the dictionary. In any case, it returns the value that's in the dictionary afterwards (so either the original value, or the new default value if there was no old value).

My code checks the return value to see if the dictionary had a value other than `my_value`. It will fail to detect the same value being added twice under the same key. I don't think there's a way to handle that situation without hashing twice.

Comment: It depends on what exactly what behavior you want, but as long as `my_value` is named, I think `is not` rather than `!=` would often make sense here.

Comment: `if my_dict.setdefault(my_key, my_value) != my_value:` might be pythonic(?), but it's confusing to me and probably could use a source code comment. Also, it only hashes once, but now it runs the `!=` implementation on `my_value` -- maybe that could be expensive, but at least in CPython it seems to be optimized when equating the same reference.

Answer (score 6):

```
my_dict.setdefault(my_key, my_value)
```

> [`setdefault(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)
>   If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

## Using the method **contains**(key)

```
my_dictionary = {"a":1, "b":2}
print(my_dictionary.__contains__('a'))
print(my_dictionary.__contains__('b'))
print(my_dictionary.__contains__('c'))
```

True

True

False

Comment: `__contains__` is the function call an `in` expression which I used in my example. Also, the question is tagged `python 3` and you've posted with `python 2`.

Comment: @Praxeolitic Added the missing parenthesis which made it so not python3. One can use the entire expression inside the print as a Boolean for a if condition. I don't see where 'in' comes in the picture

Comment: This results in hashing twice, once for `__contains__` and against for inserting

Answer (score 0):

What about storing the hashed key in a variable?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __hash__(self):
        print('MyClass.__hash__ called')
        return object.__hash__(self)

my_key = MyClass()
my_value = "my_string"
my_dict = {}

hashed_key = my_key.__hash__()

if hashed_key not in my_dict:
    my_dict[hashed_key] = my_value
else:
    raise ValueError
```

gives

```
MyClass.__hash__ called
```